# Nginx + fcgiwrap throws 502 Bad Gateway at high request rate

Tags: nginx, load-testing, fastcgi

I'm trying to scale my overpass fastcgi script  that runs under nginx, connecting via fcgiwrap.

The configuration works fine until about 140 requests/second on m4.2xlarge AWS instance.

CPU used is only 15%, and many requests start failing with 502 error code.

Obviously there are no permissions issues.

Nginx logs show :

> connect() to unix:/var/run/fcgiwrap.socket failed (11: Resource temporarily unavailable) while connecting to upstream, client: 10.0.16.100, server: , request: "POST /api/interpreter HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/fcgiwrap.socket:", host: xxxxx

and

> epoll_wait() reported that client prematurely closed connection, so upstream connection is closed too while sending request to upstream, client: 10.0.31.48, server: , request: "POST /api/interpreter HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/fcgiwrap.socket:",

I get an impressions that fcgiwrap.socket, or overpass program behind the socket cannot pipe the requests fast enough, however not sure how this can be optimized.

Nginx configuration:

```
server {
   listen 80;

location / {
     add_header Allow "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE" always;
} 

location /cgi-bin/ {
                    include        fastcgi_params;
                    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /app/$fastcgi_script_name;
                    fastcgi_param  PATH_INFO        $fastcgi_path_info;
                    fastcgi_pass   unix:/var/run/fcgiwrap.socket;
                    fastcgi_buffers 8 16k;
                    fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;
                    fastcgi_connect_timeout 300;
                    fastcgi_send_timeout 300;
                    fastcgi_read_timeout 300;
            }
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Looks like overpass-specific issue,
according to this, current overpass dispatcher v0.7.55 has very limited number of concurrent requests it can process:

https://github.com/drolbr/Overpass-API/issues/340